# PHP form textarea puts \r\n in MySQL database instead of just \n

Tags: php, mysql

Any way i can change it to use \n instead? I'm trying to save space.

This is on a Linux server.

Comment: `$value = str_replace("\r", '', $value);`

Comment: All this hassle for 1 byte per record...

Comment: *"I'm trying to save space."* - Huh? What do you have, like 500 quintilillion of these? I don't get it. Are you serious?

Comment: yes, i am serious. i have a fulltext table, with over 500,000 records, and only 1GB of space to use. i'd like to get my money's worth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$txt  = $textbox'
$txt  = str_replace("\r", '', $txt);
```

this will replace all the `\r` from the string then you can later do with it what ever you need

Comment: this doesn't exactly solve WHY it is doing it, but is a good workaround...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be use `preg_match` to confirm the existence of '\r\n' first, and then only use `preg_replace` to replace with '\n'. Your regex pattern could be as simple as '/\r\n/', depends on the data.